# unity physic.OverlapSphere as trigger

Tags: unity-game-engine, triggers, collision

I wanna make sphere collision as trigger everytime player shoot by physics.overlapsphere. but it seems like it only create make collision which is not trigger. so how can i solve this?
Collider[] cs = Physics.OverlapSphere(transform.position, redi);

```
    foreach (Collider c in cs)
    {
        Rigidbody r = c.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        if (r != null)
        {
            r.AddExplosionForce(power, transform.position, redi);
        }
        if (c.gameObject.tag == "enemy")
        {
            Destroy(c.gameObject);
        }
        if (c.gameObject.tag == "player")
        {
            c.gameObject.GetComponent<movee>().health -= 5;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Physics queries rely on `Physics.queriesHitTriggers` property which defines, if certain calls hit trigger colliders or not (see https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/QueryTriggerInteraction.html).
You can set `QueryTriggerInteraction` for your `OverlapSphere` call as a method parameter. If you do not do so, it uses the global setting, which might be set to ignore triggers in your case.

Proper method call:

```
Collider[] hitColliders = Physics.OverlapSphere(position, range, layerMaskSphere, QueryTriggerInteraction.Collide);
```

Comment: i mean i wanna overlap the trigger.

Comment: what do you mean with "overlap"

Comment: if you just want the triggers you can use `if(!c.isTrigger) continue;` inside your loop.